# How to route to a randomly generated firestore id in Vue?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vue-router

I have an app of posts with firestore as backend... In the screen where all the categories are shown, when a new category is created it's added to the list, then when a category gets clicked, I use it's id as a parameter to push the route inside that category to show the posts stored within it in a subcollection.

I'd link to find a way push the route immediately when the "Create new category" button gets clicked, instead of having to wait the category to be added to the list  ... But I don't know to do that because the id of the category is generated randomly and have no idea how to get it, any ideas?

This is my template:

```
<input v-model="newCategory" type="text" placeholder="Category name"/>
<button @click="addCategory">Create new category</button>

<div v-for="(category, index) in categories" :key="index">
  <router-link :to="{name: 'Posts', params: {categoryId: category.id}}">
    <h3>{{ category.categoryName }}</h3>
  </router-link>
</div>
```

And the script:

```
data() {
  return {
    newCategory: null,
  };
},
methods: {
  addCategory() {
    this.$firestore.categories.add({
      categoryName: this.newCategory
    });
    this.newCategory = null;
  }
},
firestore() {
  return {
    categories: db.collection("categories")
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Initialize your `categories:[]` under `data` (i don't see it applied yet)

then `this.$firestore.categories` to `this.categories` instead. The data binding should be reacting to new push/add of the array connected to Firestore

Check Example of `addTodo` method https://github.com/vuejs/vuefire/blob/master/packages/vuefire/examples/index.html

Comment: I don't see the point of this, my problem would remain the same... How can I do the `this.$router.push({ name: "posts", params: { categoryId: category.id } });` after the `.add` if I still didn't get the id that Firestore created to that category that was just added to the categories array?